# Decision on Router for small business(es)

Tags: wireless, networking, router, network-adapter

I asked my question over at SuperUser, but was directed here instead. :)

I'm currently looking for a new Router for my office, but since I live in Norway there isn't a lot of stores/webstores that cater to professional or small business needs. I called one such store out of the few we have and after explaining my needs, the woman on the other end recommended me getting either a TP-Link Talon AD7200 or the Asus RT-AC88U.

The only issue I have with either is that I cannot for the life of me find out if they have any additional wireless network segmentation capabilities. Creation of multiple SSIDs.

I rent my office space together with (at times) upwards of 20 other people, like a little office community. Most of these people run their own small business or are freelancers and one request that many wanted was the ability to have their own "space" on the network. Their own SSID that they have the password to and can connect to.

I've not dabbed this much into Networking before so I'm unsure where to look for pieces of this puzzle.

The store I'm looking at [can be found here](https://www.komplett.no/category/10273/datautstyr/nettverksprodukter) and translates almost perfectly to English.

As I said, I'm waddling blind here. I appreciate any help and insight I can get.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! Can you split this into two questions please; one about the Router and the other about the Access Point. This will allow the answers you will receive to be more focused and detailed about the hardware you are asking for.