# Access Point with multi-SSID support

Tags: wireless, networking, access-point

You can find a question I asked that's [related to this here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6279/decision-on-router-for-small-businesses).

I rent my office space together with (at times) upwards of 20 other people, like a little office community. Most of these people run their own small business or are freelancers and one request that many wanted was the ability to have their own "space" on the network. Their own SSID that they have the password to and can connect to.

I'm currently looking for a new Router/AP for my office, but since I live in Norway there isn't a lot of stored/webstores that cater to professional or small business needs.

I've not dabbed this much into Networking before so I'm unsure where to look for pieces of this puzzle.

The store I'm looking at [can be found here](https://www.komplett.no/category/10273/datautstyr/nettverksprodukter) and translates almost perfectly to English.

If none of the routers from the other question support setting up multiple SSIDs like my office mates want, I was thinking about buying an Access Point on top of the router.

Whenever I search online, it seems like most people recommend the Ubiquiti APs, the only pet-peeve I have is that I want to avoid cables wherever I can, it's preferable that the AP is wireless and not cabled.

**The question:**

For example, how would the Ubiquiti UniFi AP AC LR which to my understanding supports up to 8 SSIDs compare against the Zyxel NWA1123-AC (I read the Zyxel supports up to 16 SSIDs?) for my usage?

I have a hard time believing we'll need more than (at maximum) 20 SSIDs at the peak in our current location if that helps.

I'm very open to other suggestions as well as long as it's available at the website I provided above.

I'm struggling. I appreciate any help and insight I can get.

Thank you in advance!